# Deserializing an object that contains JSON using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using gson to deserialize POJO objects from JSON representations.

I'd like one of the fields in one of my POJOs to contain arbitrary JSON data.  For example:

```
class B {
    public String stringField;
    public JsonObject jsonField;
}
```

I'd like to be able to call `Gson.fromJson(json, B.class)` on the following JSON:

```
{
    "stringField": "booger",
    "jsonField" :
    {
        "arbitraryField1": "foo"
    }
}
```

and have the resulting `B.jsonField` contain a JsonObject with an `arbitraryField` of value `foo`.

However, when I attempt to do this, `jsonField` is always an empty object (`{}`).  In fact, more generally, it appears that the following always returns an empty object:

```
new Gson().fromJson("{ foo: 1 }", JsonObject.class)
```

I would expect the above to return an object containing a field named `foo` of value 1.

How can I have gson preserve arbitrary json data when deserializing json to POJOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem by introducing a wrapper object that contains a JsonObject, and then writing a custom deserializer for that object that simply returns the original json.  However, it seems like there must be a better way.

For posterity, the deserializer and the trivial wrapper object look like the following:

```
class MyJsonObjectWrapperDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyJsonObjectWrapper> {
    @Override
    public MyJsonObjectWrapper deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return new MyJsonObjectWrapper(json.getAsJsonObject());
    }
}

class MyJsonObjectWrapper {
    public JsonObject json;

    public MyJsonObjectWrapper(JsonObject json) {
        this.json = json;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use JsonParser:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject o = parser.parse("{ \"foo\": \"1\" }").getAsJsonObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this deserializer, which is my interpretation of [the doc](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Built-in-Serializers-and-Deserializers).

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

class B {
    public String stringField;
    public JsonObject jsonField;
}

class BDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<B> {
    public B deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
                         JsonDeserializationContext context)
                 throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

        B b = new B();
        b.stringField = jsonObject.get("stringField").getAsString();
        b.jsonField = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("jsonField"); 

        return b;
    }
}

public class Test {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
        gson.registerTypeAdapter(B.class, new BDeserializer());

        String json = " { \"stringField\" : \"booger\", \"jsonField\" : { \"arbitraryField1\" : \"foo\" } } ";

        B b = gson.create().fromJson(json, B.class);
        System.out.println(b.stringField);
        System.out.println(b.jsonField.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I could write a custom deserializer.  Which is essentially what I did in the workaround I proposed.  But it seems like a hack.  It would be nicer if there was a way that didn't involve a custom deserializer

Comment: I was researching the question and didn't see your answer when I posted. The original question gives no indication that you knew about custom deserializers and are looking for something more elegant. From the doc, it seems like this is the standard method.