# Gson deserialize into a JsonObject instead of a certain object

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have a json like this

```
{ 
    "host":"a-host.com",
    "port":1234,
    "other":{ 
        "messageVersion":1,
        "anotherObject":{ 

        }
    }
}
```

My intention is to parse the json except what's in "other". Is that possible?

Currently, I am able to parse all the fields successfully, but when it comes to the "other" field, I get an empty object "{}". Why is that happening?

```
    @SerializedName("host")
    private String host;
    @SerializedName("port")
    private int port;
    @SerializedName("other")
    private JsonObject other;
```

Comment: it is unclear what problem you are having .... you said that you do not want to parse "other"

Comment: I want the whole json object existing into "other" parsed into a JsonObject.

Comment: Is this [Deserializing an object that contains JSON using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12381088/8498513) answer your question?

Comment: I think OP wants to parse `other` as a JSONObject rather than parsing into a java POJO. @mbob Please update your question with code where you are pasring the json.

Comment: @DinarZaripov yeah, it seems this is what I need. Weird. I wasn't expecting to need a custom deserializer. Thanks! I will mark this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to parse the "other", just remove the code related to it from DTO/POJO and run the program. It should work fine.

```
@SerializedName("other")
private JsonObject other;
```

Comment: i want to have it parsed into a JsonObject. With this implementation, the other object contains an empty object "{}"

Comment: @mbob really what you want to do

Answer (score -1):

you can check following code.

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class GSONExample {

    private static String json = "YOUR JSON";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        ItemDob itemDob = gson.fromJson(json, ItemDob.class);
        System.out.println(itemDob.getOther());
    }

}

class ItemDob {
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private JsonObject other;

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public JsonObject getOther() {
        return other;
    }

    public void setOther(JsonObject other) {
        this.other = other;
    }
}
```

Value of `other` (itemDob.getOther()) is printed as

> {"messageVersion":1,"anotherObject":{}}

Comment: Can you update your question with your code for serialization to pojo?